# Como asignar color verde con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en javascript y estoy intentando realizar una tabla donde una columna tiene valores dimanicos, quiere que dependiendo del valor se de un color en el fondo, tengo este código pero no siempre me está funcionando.

Tuve que colorcar diferentes nombres en las variables, ya que antes las tenía como dato, dato1 y así sucesivamente pero no toma el color

```js
var dato = document.getElementById("dato");
 var datoTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt");
 console.log(dato);
       function cambio(){    
             if (dato.value <= "20") {
                 datoTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (dato.value > "20" && dato.value <= "29") {
                 datoTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (dato.value > "29") {
                 datoTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         datoTxt.innerHTML = dato.value;
         cambio();
var cruce = document.getElementById("dato1");
 var cruceTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt1");
 console.log(cruce);
       function change(){    
             if (cruce.value <= "10") {
                 cruceTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (cruce.value >= "11" && cruce.value < "16") {
                 cruceTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (cruce.value > "16") {
                 cruceTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         cruceTxt.innerHTML = cruce.value;
         change();
         
 var across = document.getElementById("dato2");
 var acrossTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt2");
 console.log(across);
       function modi(){    
             if (across.value < "6") {
                 acrossTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (across.value > "6" && across.value <= "11") {
                 acrossTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (across.value > "11") {
                 acrossTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         acrossTxt.innerHTML = across.value;
         modi();
         
 var trasn = document.getElementById("dato3");
 var trasnTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt3");
 console.log(across);
       function exchange(){    
             if (trasn.value <= "19") {
                 trasnTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (trasn.value > "19" && trasn.value <= "28") {
                 trasnTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (trasn.value > "28") {
                 trasnTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         trasnTxt.innerHTML = trasn.value;
         exchange();
         
  var alteracion = document.getElementById("dato4");
 var alteracionTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt4");
 console.log(alteracion);
       function canje(){    
             if (alteraciontrasn.value <= "29") {
                 alteracionTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (alteracion.value > "29" && alteracion.value <= "39") {
                 alteracionTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (alteracion.value > "39") {
                 alteracionTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         alteracionTxt.innerHTML = alteracion.value;
         canje();
         
var nota = document.getElementById("dato5");
 var notaTxt = document.getElementById("datoTxt5");
 console.log(nota);
       function mudanza(){    
             if (nota.value <= "11") {
                 notaTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#c0392b";
             }else if (nota.value > "11" && nota.value <= "18") {
                 notaTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#f2df0e";
             }else if (nota.value > "18") {
                 notaTxt.style.backgroundColor = "#32aa0d";
             }
         } 
         notaTxt.innerHTML = nota.value;
         mudanza();
```

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div class="container">
<div id="table" style="padding: 15px; text-align: center;">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr >
  <th>Estado</th>
  <th>Índice</th>
  <th>Enviados</th>
  <th>Entregados</th>
  <th>Aperturas</th>
 </tr>
<tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
<td>Maduración</td>
<td id="datoTxt"><input type="hidden" id="dato" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURAMADURACION}"><span ></span></td>
<td>{Query.MADURACIONENVIOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.MADURACIONENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.MADURACIONOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Remarketing</td>
<td id="datoTxt1"><input type="hidden" id="dato1" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURAREMARKETING}"></td>
<td>{Query.REMARKETINGENVIOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.REMARKETINGENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.REMARKETINGOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
<td>High School</td>
<td id="datoTxt2"><input type="hidden" id="dato2" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURAHIGHSCHOOL}"><span ></span></td>
<td>{Query.HIGHSCHOOLENVIOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.HIGHSCHOOLENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.HIGHSCHOOLOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rematricula</td>
<td id="datoTxt3"><input type="hidden" id="dato3" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURAREMATRICULA}"><span ></span></td>
<td>{Query.REMATRICULAENVIOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.REMATRICULAENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.REMATRICULAOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
<td>Permanencia</td>
<td id="datoTxt4"><input type="hidden" id="dato4" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURAPERMANENCIA}"><span ></span></td>
<td>{Query.PERMANENCIAENVIOSTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.PERMANENCIAENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.PERMANENCIAOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Recupero</td>
<td id="datoTxt5"><input type="hidden" id="dato5" value="{Query.INDICEDEAPERTURARECUPERO}"><span ></span></td>
<td>{Query.RECUPEROENVIOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.RECUPEROENTREGADOTOTAL}</td>
<td>{Query.RECUPEROOPENTOTAL}</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Aquí podrán ver mi código, las llaves que dicen Query es de donde obtengo mis datos de manera dinámica.

Comment: Hola John Edison, parece que no se copió bien la parte del final de la pregunta. Por favor edítala para aclararla. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).